# Golang protobufs has a name conflict over

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have two services that talk to each other and have separate protofiles.  There are a couple of messages type common between the two. When an attempt to test run I get:

```
  2020/08/24 13:40:42 WARNING: proto: file "delivery.proto" has a name
  conflict over release.Patient     previously from:
 "gitlab.com/dhf0820/roirelease/protobufs/relPB"    currently from: 
 "gitlab.com/dhf0820/roi_delivery/protobufs/delPB"
```

As you can see they have different package names relPB and delPB. The patient is used in both services and I marshal/unmarshal between the two to send the proper message. I am not sure if this is the correct way.

Is there a better way or what is going on. I seem to be having unique names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the names are unique in the generated *Go code domain*, but not in the *protobuf domain*.

You can really view protobuf as its own language, with its own package and namespace semantics (in practice, similar to C++). In that domain, the actual file names don't matter, only the package defined in the file.

Both your files probably have `package release;` at the top. This means that, in the protobuf world, `release.Patient` is defined twice. `protoc` may still be able to generate working Go code by accident, but it's still a malformed proto definition. You may not have the same luck if you try to use the same definition in other languages (e.g. C++) or if you try to use libraries that depend on proto reflection. It may also break if you try to use one of the messages as a field in another file; which `release.Patient` will that refer to?